# Creating a boundary between objects (python)

Tags: python, objects

So I'm trying to create a visual line that is used between 2 objects. A basic example here:

[image]

Where the white lines represent a boundary between the 2 objects (the 2 blue lines)

These boundaries basically stick to the right and left point of each object and connect together.

A more complex example:

[image]

The idea is so when I create an object it creates these lines that connect from that previous object to the next one.

So what I've attempted:

**Bones**
This method seems to work pretty well. The major issue is creating these points when a new object is created. One bone point can stay at the current object and the other point at the newly created object.

So if I wanted to duplicate it like this:

[image]

I would want it to duplicate the bone points along with it creating this boundary I want.

[image]

So it would have to extrude the bones at the same time as the object gets duplicated.

So some code I messed with:

```
for ob in bpy.data.objects:

arm = ob.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
for i in range(3):
    bpy.ops.armature.extrude()
```

This simply extrudes it just how I want it. However this duplicates them in edit mode preventing me from duplicated the other object along with it. (Object need to be a separate object too when duplicated)

**Constraints**

For this test I went ahead and attempted to use a stretch to constraint with a basic object on each path. This however didn't give good results for what I wanted. Spacing would be weird, and having to setup specific axis could

If anyone has any ideas or ways I could improve upon my ideas that would be great!

Comment: How would Blender know which object follows another object? Do you maintain a list of sorts? Is there some naming convention?

Comment: These objects are sorted in a list by name from `objects = sorted(bpy.context.scene.objects, key=lambda ob: ob.name)`. Each object starts with "Lap" in the name to represent the path object it is then just has numbers at the end, .001, .002, .003 ect.

Comment: Is it for the viewport only? How many objects are we talking about?

Comment: It's for just the viewport and entirely visual just to know the boundries between the objects. There isn't quite a particular amount as these are used for any amount the user may want to add for their map. These simply represent the boundaries the player cannot go out of in a racing game. where a plane covers the X Y Z of how much a player can go and they connect to each other.